# Launching the standard Contacts View from my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, contacts

What I am trying to accomplish with my app is if a user clicks on a contact name in my app. I want to directly launch the selected contact in a new view, but using the standard ios contact view.  Is this possible?  If so how can it be accomplished?  I can't seem to find any URL Scheme for the contacts app if one does indeed exist that is.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Address Book UI framework documentation, please.

By the way, using this framework is a very good idea i.e. "the standard iOS contact view", because trying to reproduce this view and all its functionality yourself would be, shall we say, challenging.

Comment: Also here's my discussion: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch31.html#_address_book_interface

Comment: And here's a downloadable project where you can try out the four different view controllers: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch18p713addressBook/ch31p973addressBook/ViewController.m

Comment: thanks, I'll have a look at the link.  You are correct, I figured replicating it would be a total chore and probably not a productive way to use my time when I can easily just launch the contacts view if it's possible.

Comment: This isn't launching the contacts app but it's exactly the same interface (inside _your_ app). Basically they've handed you the contacts app interface on a platter.

Comment: so I implemented the ABPersonViewController like in the example provided in the first link you have.  It kind of worked, but not what I was expecting.  All it showed was the contact name and that was it.  I was expecting to see all the contact information.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. Do not copy the example slavishly. It's just an example. Read the documentation. Study each line. Understand it. Modify it so that all the contact information does appear. Stand on your own two feet.

Comment: ok, my bad for not reading it in more detail.  I did read that part now in more detail and noticed that part where I can control what is displayed.  I did make that change and it's still not showing all the other info.  This is my first ios app, so sometimes I struggle with some of the logic and maybe my questions may seem obvious.  But thanks for the help anyway, I'll keep researching.

Comment: I tested my own code just now, removing the line that limits what's shown, and sure enough everything about that person (contact) does show up. Perhaps you are not accessing the contact record you think you are...?